# Dependent variable with negative values

Tags: multivariate-analysis, independence

Using a questionnaire, I quantitatively obtain the value of a symptom in a patient (that is, an ordinal variable). I apply this questionnaire twice, these occasions are separated by a period of one year. By subtracting these two values (the one found initially and after one year) I obtain a third variable that I will use as a dependent variable (this variable will show how the symptom has progressed). I have other variables that I will use as independent variables (age, sex, race). The problem is that sometimes by subtracting the two values I get a negative result (this results because in some patients the symptom worsens and in others it improves). My goal is to measure which independent variables influence symptom progression.

What type of test can I use? or what transformation can i do to the dependent variable? or Can I run a regression analysis with negative values on the dependent variable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd say that the formulation of your dependent variable is one approach to doing this, and the inclusion of negative values should not affect the results necessarily. It really depends on your research question. If the question is whether these factors led to an improvement or not, you could create a binary dependent variable (0 for not improved or 1 for improved).

You would typically not use a test for this type of question, but use some type of multivariate regression. However, with the limited data you have (two data points), the results are likely to be spurious.

Comment: I am currently designing the research, in fact I could add more data points, for example I could evaluate the patient every two months and in this way I could obtain the difference in score between each evaluation and the base evaluation ; in the latter case, could I run an ordinal regression or do you suggest another? It is very difficult for me to convert the dependent variable into dichotomous.

Comment: Converting the variable to a dichotomous format would not be too difficult. You would take the difference and then might right some code that says if Y is positive, code it as 1, and 0 if negative or no change. Again, it really depends on the question you'd like to ask.

Comment: My question is: Does race, sex or age significantly influence the worsening of disease symptom?